# Devise Authenticated Block Issue with Rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I am using mongoid, Rails 3.1.0 and Devise 1.5.3.

In my routes.rb i have an authenticated block.

```
authenticated :user do
  get "dashboard" => ":controller#:action", constraints: lambda { |r| not r.env['warden'].user(:user).primary_account.nil? }
  root to: ":controller#:action", constraints: lambda { |r| not r.env['warden'].user(:user).primary_account.nil? }

end
```

upon loading of the app, it proceeds inside the block even without the user being authenticated through devise. This causes an error on the user object part as it is still nil upon loading. Any suggestions?